# Soy estudiante de primer año y queria saber como agregar algo a una variable

Tags: python, variables-globales

Mi problema seria que no se como agregar el segundo nombre, no se como sumarlo. Abajo les dejo el enunciado:
En la comisión E están creando el registro histórico de delegados/as del curso. Para ellos quieren ahora un procedimiento que les permita registrar los/las delegados/as del curso en cada año en la variable global delegados_por_año

```
registrar_delegado_del_año("Sol", 2021)
registrar_delegado_del_año("Perla", 2022)
delegados_por_año
Sol 2021, Perla 2022
```

Y esto es lo que yo hice

```
def registrar_delegados_por_año(delegados, año):
  global delegados_por_año
  delegados_por_año = delegados + " "+  str(año)+ "," 
  delegados_por_año
```

Y me devuelve esto:

```
registrar_delegados_por_año("Pablo", 2021)
delegados_por_año
registrar_delegados_por_año("Alfredo", 2022)
delegados_por_año

Alfredo 2022,
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre. De paso, explica exactamente tu problema.. y aclara el lenguaje con la etiqueta correspondiente...

Comment: Una variable solo puede tener un valor.. si queres guardar mas de un valor, tu variable tiene que ser una lista o similar.. igual, procura agregar tu codigo a la pregunta...

Comment: Se te permite el uso del método [str.join](https://blog.carreralinux.com.ar/2017/07/uso-split-y-join-python/) y listas? Ya vieron esos temas? La variable global ya te la dan inicializada o podes inicializarla vos? Si te la dan inicializada, sabes con que valor?

Answer (score 0):

primero que nada, esto lo estás haciendo en python, no?
No tengo experiencia en ese lenguaje, pero buscando un poco encontré que se puede hacer lo siguiente:

### Usando lista y objetos: (Opción más completa)

```py
// Crear una variable
delegados_por_anio = [];

// Esto lo que hace es crear una función que recibe un delegado, un año y le hace un append a la lista global de arriba

def registrar_delegados_por_anio(anio, delegado):
  delegados_por_anio.append({ anio, delegado })
  
//llamo a la función de mas arriba 3 veces agregandole 3 delegados.
registrar_delegados_por_anio(2002, "lucas")
registrar_delegados_por_anio(2005, "nicolas")
registrar_delegados_por_anio(2004, "juan")

// Hago un print para ver los elementos de la lista
print(delegados_por_anio)
```

```json
[{2002, 'lucas'}, {2005, 'nicolas'}, {'juan', 2004}]
```

### Usando listas y strings:

```py
delegados_por_anio = []

def registrar_delegados_por_anio(anio, delegado):
  delegados_por_anio.append(f'{anio}, {delegado}')

registrar_delegados_por_anio(2002, "lucas")
registrar_delegados_por_anio(2005, "nicolas")
registrar_delegados_por_anio(2004, "juan")

print(delegados_por_anio)
```

La clave está en que la variable global sea una lista o un array para poder guardar mas de un objeto.

### Usando solo strings (La opción más simple)

```py
delegados_por_anio = ""

def registrar_delegados_por_anio(anio, delegado):
    global delegados_por_anio
    delegado = str(anio) + ' ' + str(delegado) + ', \n'
    delegados_por_anio += delegado

registrar_delegados_por_anio(2002, "lucas")
registrar_delegados_por_anio(2005, "nicolas")
registrar_delegados_por_anio(2004, "juan")

print(delegados_por_anio)
```

Salida:

```
2002 lucas, 
2005 nicolas, 
2004 juan,
```

Comment: Por otro lado, solo para aclarar, está buenisimo que la gente participe y pregunte cosas, pero sería muchísimo mejor si la pregunta fuera mucho mas clara, por ejemplo respetando ciertas normas, preguntando diciendo un lenguaje específico y una duda específica :)

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, es por eso que en los comentarios se le sugirió al autor leer las secciones [ask] y [tour], y por lo mismo otros usuarios no habían dado respuestas ya que una pregunta que no es clara o que no muestra un intento por resolver su problema no debería ser respondida ya que fomenta la holgazanería. Y cuando las preguntas incluyen más de un tema es perjudicial para otros usuarios que podrían tener un problema similar, pero al incluir muchas preguntas es más difícil encontrar la información. Saludos